# "the specified procedure could not be found" while using oracle in node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle

I try to connect and execute an SQL query on oracle (DB) via node.js .

I use oracleDB npm.

while I try to connect via the function of the npm I get this bizarre error:

```
Error: the specified procedure could not be found.
..../oracledb.node
at Error(native(at Object.Module._extensions..node(module.js:422:18(
at module.load(module.js:343:32(
at function.module._load(module.js:300:12(
at Module.require(module.js:353:17(
at require(internal/module:12:17(
at Object.<anonymous>
(PATH)\module\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:35:19(at Module._compile(module.js:397:26(at Object.Module._extension..js (module.js:404:10(at module.load(module.js:343:32)
```

Thank you!